# org.hibernate.MappingException in one of the entity which is a part of one to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, relationship

Getting the below exception while starting my spring boot project-
**Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.learning.api.Flights.Entities.Airport, at table: flight_schedule, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(destination)]**

The entities am using are as below.

**Airline**

```
    package org.learning.api.Flights.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity(name="Airline")
public class Airline {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "airline")
    private Set<FlightSchedule> flightSchedules;

    public Airline() {
    }

    public Airline(Long id, String name, Set<FlightSchedule> flightSchedules) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.flightSchedules = flightSchedules;
    }

    public Airline(String name, Set<FlightSchedule> flightSchedules) {
        this.name = name;
        this.flightSchedules = flightSchedules;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<FlightSchedule> getFlightSchedules() {
        return flightSchedules;
    }

    public void setFlightSchedules(Set<FlightSchedule> flightSchedules) {
        this.flightSchedules = flightSchedules;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Airline airline = (Airline) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, airline.id) && Objects.equals(name, airline.name) && Objects.equals(flightSchedules, airline.flightSchedules);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, flightSchedules);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Airline{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", flightSchedules=" + flightSchedules +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Airport**

```
package org.learning.api.Flights.Entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity(name="Airport")
public class Airport {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String city;

    public Airport() {
    }

    public Airport(Long id, String name, String city) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Airport(String name, String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Airport airport = (Airport) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, airport.id) && Objects.equals(name, airport.name) && Objects.equals(city, airport.city);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, city);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Airport{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Flight**

```
package org.learning.api.Flights.Entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.Objects;
@Entity(name = "Flight")
public class Flight {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String company;
private String modelName;
    public Flight(){}

    public Flight(Long id, String company, String modelName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.company = company;
        this.modelName = modelName;
    }

    public Flight(String company, String modelName) {
        this.company = company;
        this.modelName = modelName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getModelName() {
        return modelName;
    }

    public void setModelName(String modelName) {
        this.modelName = modelName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flight{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", company='" + company + '\'' +
                ", modelName='" + modelName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Flight flight = (Flight) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, flight.id) && Objects.equals(company, flight.company) && Objects.equals(modelName, flight.modelName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, company, modelName);
    }
}
```

**FlightSchedule**

```
package org.learning.api.Flights.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity(name="FlightSchedule")
public class FlightSchedule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Airline airline;
    private Flight flight;
    private Airport source;
    private Airport destination;
    private Date scheduledDeparture;
    private Date scheduledArrival;

    public FlightSchedule() {
    }

    public FlightSchedule(Long id, Airline airline, Flight flight, Airport source, Airport destination, Date scheduledDeparture, Date scheduledArrival) {
        this.id = id;
        this.airline = airline;
        this.flight = flight;
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.scheduledDeparture = scheduledDeparture;
        this.scheduledArrival = scheduledArrival;
    }

    public FlightSchedule(Airline airline, Flight flight, Airport source, Airport destination, Date scheduledDeparture, Date scheduledArrival) {
        this.airline = airline;
        this.flight = flight;
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.scheduledDeparture = scheduledDeparture;
        this.scheduledArrival = scheduledArrival;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Airline getAirline() {
        return airline;
    }

    public void setAirline(Airline airline) {
        this.airline = airline;
    }

    public Flight getFlight() {
        return flight;
    }

    public void setFlight(Flight flight) {
        this.flight = flight;
    }

    public Airport getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(Airport source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public Airport getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(Airport destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public Date getScheduledDeparture() {
        return scheduledDeparture;
    }

    public void setScheduledDeparture(Date scheduledDeparture) {
        this.scheduledDeparture = scheduledDeparture;
    }

    public Date getScheduledArrival() {
        return scheduledArrival;
    }

    public void setScheduledArrival(Date scheduledArrival) {
        this.scheduledArrival = scheduledArrival;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        FlightSchedule that = (FlightSchedule) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) && Objects.equals(airline, that.airline) && Objects.equals(flight, that.flight) && Objects.equals(source, that.source) && Objects.equals(destination, that.destination) && Objects.equals(scheduledDeparture, that.scheduledDeparture) && Objects.equals(scheduledArrival, that.scheduledArrival);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, airline, flight, source, destination, scheduledDeparture, scheduledArrival);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FlightSchedule{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", airline=" + airline +
                ", flight=" + flight +
                ", source=" + source +
                ", destination=" + destination +
                ", scheduledDeparture=" + scheduledDeparture +
                ", scheduledArrival=" + scheduledArrival +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing `@ManyToOne` on `FlightSchedule.destination`,  `FlightSchedule.source` and probably on `FlightSchedule.flight`.

Comment: I need to build a one to many relation ship between just airline and flight schedules. One Airline can have many flight schedules. So is it mandatory to give the @ManyToOne on all of the members of the FlightSchedules class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as answer: Looks like you are missing @ManyToOne on `FlightSchedule.destination`, `FlightSchedule.source` and on `FlightSchedule.flight`.

The more detailed answer. Hibernate needs to know how to link a `FlightSchedule` with an `Airport`. At the moment, the code doesn't have any annotations that hint how this mapping should work. It could be any of the potential mapping types. Since an Airport can be the source or destination of many schedules, the relationship needs to be many-to-one.

By adding `@ManyToOne` you tell hibernate that you want a column in the table `flight_schedule`, with a foreign key to the table `airport`, and this is what it uses later to join the columns and retrieve the associated airport when you load a flight schedule. The same applies to `FlightSchedule.flight`

I hope the above makes sense! If you want to see some examples of mapping you can take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/augusto/jpa-workshop/tree/master/src/main/java/com/ig/training/hibernate/domainmodel). The hibernate docs are  (usually) quite good: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations